# when i try to change column name for max(value) inside a view in sql it shows error

Tags: sql, postgresql

this is my code and it is getting employee no#, name, dept_name , dept_no and last paid salary and also last date when the salary was paid..

```
create or replace view  last_salary_change as 
SELECT e.emp_no , e.first_name,d.dept_no,f.dept_name ,
 max(s.salary) as "max salary", max(s.from_date) as "max date"
from salaries as s
join employees as e using(emp_no)
join dept_emp as d using(emp_no)
join departments as f using(dept_no)

group by e.emp_no,d,dept_no,f.dept_name
order by emp_no;
```

the error i get is:

> Kernel error: ERROR:  cannot change name of view column "max" to "max salary"

I have two max() in one query so i have to change the column name otherwise it gives other error of two same column name.

How to change column name of max() inside a view?

Comment: Check this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/589/170431

Comment: Also be careful of the following typo: `group by e.emp_no, d,dept_no, f.dept_name` should be: `group by e.emp_no, d.dept_no, f.dept_name`

Comment: You need to drop the view first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `create or replace view`, you cannot change the names or data types of the columns already defined in the view (if the view already exists).

This is well [documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html):

> The new query must generate the same columns that were generated by the existing view query (that is, the same column names in the same order and with the same data types), but it may add additional columns to the end of the list. The calculations giving rise to the output columns may be completely different.

To change the name of columns that already exist, you need to `drop` the view and then recreate it:

```
drop view if exists last_salary_change;

create view last_salary_change as
    . . . ;
```

I should also point out that if the last salary is not a raise, then `max(salary)` is not the most recent salary.  If you intend the most recent salary, ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data, desired results, and explanation of what you are trying to do.

Note:  I also strongly recommend avoid naming that need to be escaped.  So instead of `"max salary"` and `"max date"`, use `max_salary` and `max_date`.

Comment: max is the most recent because i am also quering max(from_date) which gives the latest date and gives back the max_salary according to that and by the way this worked thanks. and for naming convention i changed that too.. <3